# Win 7 machine going into sleep like state randomly

Tags: windows-7

A colleague of mine uses a Win 7 machine in a server like configuration that runs the security camera software. Now the issue is that this machine for no apparent reason goes into a sleep like state, I say sleep like state because the machine clearly has power and appears to be running but does not react to anything. The software does not run in this state. I checked the Event logs but they just stop at the time the state starts. Getting it back online requires a force shutdown. I assumed it was updates at first but after manually testing by forcing updates the machine seemed to restart just fine. Does anyone know where the fault could be?

Comment: Have you checked the power settings?

Comment: I did, since it's not a laptop I don't get the sleep mode options

Comment: Try to disable C6 feature of CPU in BIOS settings.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem while running batch jobs that takes a long time in my PC. Usually this can be fixed quickly by reviewing the power settings.

A quick workaround if you dont wana mess up with the power setting is play a video/movie in a loop.
My company doesnt allows movies so i use the default video sample under - "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos" and that keeps the PC in active mode always untill i manually shut it down... 
hope that helps :)

Comment: But shouldn't the security camera software have the same effect? For some reason it's not something that just runs in the background but also shows the video output of all cameras.